# How to store or access payload data in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I'm new to redux, but i have one question make me so confuse, so suppose we have an Reducer like this

```
initState = {
  loginStatus: false,
};
const LoginAction = (state = initState, action) => {
  if (action.type == changeLogin) {
    return { loginStatus: !state.loginStatus };
  } else if (action.type == getDefault) {
    return { loginStatus: false };
  }
  return state;
};
export default LoginAction;
```

Access to this reducer data is easy, to get `loginStatus` , just `state.LoginStatus` by use `useSelector` hook but if i have a action like this

```
export const GetUserInfo = (user, password) => ({
  type: actionList.GET_USER_INFO,
  data: { user, password },
});
```

How can i access or change data inside these payload `(user, password)`??
Thank you very much for help

Comment: `action.data.user` and `action.data.password`? Are you asking how to access the action properties in a reducer? Can you clarify your question or what the issue is?

Comment: I mean access data in a main file, for example, a main file as a login screen, `login.js` i use `useSelector`  to access Reducer item, but i don't know how to use that with item in `action` file

Comment: React UI doesn't use the action objects, it dispatches them to the redux store.

Comment: So how can i access these item, i'm new to redux so maybe this question is a little dumb but i really don't know how to do that, offical redux doc make me more confuse :(

Comment: You need to handle the action in a reducer, update some state, and select that out of state in your UI just like you did `state.loginStatus`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it would be nice if you recommend for me some easy to understand redux tutorial, right now , i honestly still don't understand what you said, i mean how to but i will find out, or you can give me an example for this, that would be great, i'm very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching the official documentation for the redux that might help you to build your app.

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started